# Меню в 3 колонки на WP

Tags: wordpress, menu

Нужно сделать меню на WP с такой структурой:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Demo</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть какие-то идеи как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Когда выводите меню через `wp_nav_menu` https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu у этой функции агрумент walker. Вы можете создать родительский класс для Walker и передать его в этот параметр. В самом классе можно как угодно изменять вид меню.

Пример: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu#walker

И документация на класс Walker: https://wp-kama.ru/function/walker